# Counting identical cells excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a long list of data in column A which is a combination of numbers and text.
eg)

1. cow / 20 / 3000
2. cow / 30 / 3000
3. pig / 20 / 4000
4. cow / 20 / 3000

In another column I would like a list of all these values without the duplicates and then I would like excel to count the number of times each cell is repeated, So cow / 20 / 3000 would have the number 2 next to it, and all other values would have 1 as they only appear once in the list.

Please also note, the cells are collected from elsewhere in the document and have OFFSET formulas attached.

Any Ideas?

Comment: This is a typical use of a pivot table. Add your column as row labels, and also as values.

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with pivot tables, please could you explain a little further. Many Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is a typical use of a pivot table. Add your column as row labels, and also as values.

[image]

Comment: My complication is that the data automatically updates when changes are made in other sheets - but the pivot table seems to not update? I.e if i changed all 'cow' entries to 'duck' the table remains with 'cow'.....Is there any way to have the pivot table update automatically?

Comment: You need to use macros for that: http://www.eonesolutions.com/blog-post/tech-tues-automatically-refreshing-pivot-tables-excel-refreshable-reports/

Comment: Oh no I'm not very good with macros haha. Thanks for the link

Answer (score 0):

Here is a formula solution that will dynamically adjust for changing data.  In **B1** enter:

```
=A1
```

In **B2** enter the *array formula*:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$1000,INT(SMALL(IF(COUNTIF(B$1:B1,$A$1:$A$1000)=0,ROW($A$1:$A$1000)+(COLUMN($A$1:$A$1000)*0.01)),1)),100*MOD(SMALL(IF(COUNTIF(B$1:B1,$A$1:$A$1000)=0,ROW($A$1:$A$1000)+(COLUMN($A$1:$A$1000)*0.01)),1),1)),"")
```

and copy downwards.  Column **B** will show the unique values, followed by a zero, followed by blanks.  In **C1** enter:

```
=IF(ROWS($1:1)<SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(B:B)<>0)),COUNTIF(A:A,B1),"")
```

and copy downwards:

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

You can ignore the ***0*** at the bottom col column **B**.  If you insert/delete/change data in column **A**, columns **B** and **C** will adjust automatically

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you might ne able to experiment using a FUNCTION. Make a copy of your worksheet to use as an experimental model. Use the following function as a starting point and extend/adjust the range and syntax accordingly:

=IF(COUNTIF(D$6:D$450,D6)>1,"Duplicated","")

Imagine an Invoice Register, say, columns A B C D displaying Date, Supplier, Invoice Number, Invoice Amount. Placed in say, cell E6 copied and pasted in cells E7 to E450, this is what the above function does:

Prints the word "Duplicated" if an invoice number appears more than once.